# video.js techOrder flash - no compatible source was found for this video

Tags: flash, html5-video, video.js

Whenever I try to run a video with `data-setup='{"techOrder": ["flash"]}'` set at only flash I can't make it work.

- Here is a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/a9uvasrh/5/
- The fiddle from this other SO Q&A also doesn't load for me [Video.js Force Flash Controls Display](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24958353/video-js-force-flash-controls-display)

Tested on Chrome, Opera, FF and IE . Only the last 2 show the message "no compatible source was found for this video"; the others remain unresponsive.

---

Edit: The issue is present in local storage as well

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="http://vjs.zencdn.net/c/video-js.css"></script>
        <script src="http://vjs.zencdn.net/c/video.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <video id="example_video_1" class="video-js vjs-default-skin"
              controls preload="auto" width="640" height="264"
              poster="http://video-js.zencoder.com/oceans-clip.png"
              data-setup='{"techOrder": ["flash"]}'>
                 <source src="http://video-js.zencoder.com/oceans-clip.mp4" type='video/mp4' />
                 <source src="http://video-js.zencoder.com/oceans-clip.webm" type='video/webm' />
                 <source src="http://video-js.zencoder.com/oceans-clip.ogv" type='video/ogg' />
                 <p class="vjs-no-js">To view this video please enable JavaScript, and consider upgrading to a web browser that <a href="http://videojs.com/html5-video-support/" target="_blank">supports HTML5 video</a></p>
            </video>
        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

The code above initializes the flash player (VideoJS Flash component v3.0  appears in the dropdown menu) but it doesn't run the video.

Comment: I'm not sure what's going on here. I get this even going back to version 3.2 of video.js with fiddles that previously worked, so I'd say something about jsfiddle or Flash has changed.

Comment: Yeah, I'm not sure what's going on there. JSbin blocks flash in the edit mode, and maybe jsfiddle is doing the same now. This jsbin (not in edit mode) works for me. http://jsbin.com/xezab/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because jsfiddle is now using the [`sandbox` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe#attr-sandbox) on the iframe the results are shown in. The effect of that varies: In Chrome the swf is loaded but Flash's `ExternalInterface` is blocked, so the swf can't be told to do anything. In Firefox the swf doesn't even get loaded.

jsbin's also uses an iframe with `sandbox` in edit mode, but works fine out of edit mode as no iframe is used.

Assuming that "local storage" means the html is being loaded in the browser with the `file://` protocol then the problem is also the browser blocking ExternalInterface script access, but for a different reason. Here it's because browsers block script access to a swf loaded over one protocol (`http`) from a page loaded over another (`file`).

Comment: I editted my question to show that my problems with the flash player are not jsfiddle based

Comment: It took me 2 days to find this and was about to give a new answer when I saw you had included the part about local storage with an edit. In future edits, please provide a comment, as edits alone don't send notifications it seems... or I missed it

Comment: Sorry about that, I thought you would be notified as a commenter if not as the asker.